# Copying files network drive getting around 260 character limit C#

Tags: c#

Right now i'm attempting to take a screenshot and save it to the local machine, then later copy it to a network drive:

Q:\1234567890123456789012345\123456789012\12345\Screenshots\sc.jpg

^ for an idea about how many characters were talking. I have it setup to create a screenshots folder after that "12345" When the program gets to the point this error occurs:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Also:

```
DirectoryInfo scdestinfo = new DirectoryInfo(scdest);
DirectoryInfo scinfo = new DirectoryInfo(sccpath);
CopyAll(scinfo, scdestinfo);
```

That's my code for copying the folders/files.

```
public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        copyall = false;
        try
        {
            //check if the target directory exists
            if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
            }//end if
            //copy all the files into the new directory
            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
            }//end foreach
            //copy all the sub directories using recursion
            foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceDir in source.GetDirectories())
            {
                DirectoryInfo nextTargetDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceDir.Name);
                CopyAll(diSourceDir, nextTargetDir);
            }//end foreach
            //success here
            copyall = true;    
        }//end try
        catch (IOException ie)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ie.Message);
            //handle it here
            copyall = false;
        }//end catch
    }//end CopyAll
```

And the copyall function.

Comment: I've attempted to in the past, but was worried it wouldn't work over multiple versions of windows. (ie. XP - 7) Hence why I'm looking  for an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Windows limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx), though there are Unicode variants of many API functions that allow for a maximum path length of approximately 32,767 characters, though that is again limited by the specific file system you are dealing with.  Typically a given path component is limited to 255 characters (check [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993.aspx) for the specific limitation for a given volume).

To use the Unicode variants (e.g. [CreateFileW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that allow for longer paths, I believe you will have to deal with the Windows API directly rather than using the .Net library functions.

Comment: I ended up checking this one out along with the other answer, but this one a bit more it looks like it'll work will just take some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward way to avoid this, unfortunately.

Solution1: most natural one: generate a path in a way that it doesn't go over that limit.(shorter directory and file names) , or just reorganize directories layout, if this is possible.

Solution2: Don't like this one (wired, imo), but can use `WindowsAPI`, that doesn't fail in that case, like from the [.NET 2.0 Workaround for PathTooLongException](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22013/NET-2-0-Workaround-for-PathTooLongException) (it's for 2.0, but valid for nowdays)

Solution3. *Try*, when you're going to read/write data to a file, move OS cursor to that directory, so you will not need to specify complete (260+) to access it, but just file name. **You should try this to see if it works for you**. (even if this works I would prefer the first solution, but it worths to try)

Hope this helps.